# Swift 2: Local Notification at Bottom of Screen instead of Middle

Tags: ios, swift

My application is displaying local notifications at the bottom of the screen instead of in the middle as they are the rest of the time. I have a picture below that shows my problem. I also attached my code below for reference. I've created a function called displayAlert so I don't have to keep repeating that same code for other alerts.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjTij.png)

```
func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var seperated = emailLabel.text?.componentsSeparatedByString("@")
    let username = seperated![0]

    if emailLabel.text != "" && passwordLabel.text != ""
    {
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,50,50))
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .Gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password: passwordLabel.text!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            if user != nil
            {
                // Logged in!
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.loginSegue, sender: self)
            }
            else
            {
                // Failed loggin in
                if let errorCode = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String
                {
                    self.errorMessage = errorCode
                }

                self.displayAlert("Failed Log In", message: self.errorMessage)
            }
        })

    }
    else
    {
        displayAlert("Error", message: "Please enter your email and password!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code you're using to display the notification

Comment: Doesn't look like a local notification to me.

Comment: is this view controller a child of another view controller? what is its view frame?

Answer (score 1):

change `preferredStyle: .actionSheet` to `preferredStyle: .alert` to display it modally as per docs https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller/1620092-init